# retrieve lat and long from given address in struts2

Tags: google-maps, struts2

I'm beginning to use google maps api. And I have a problem with geocode, I have lost time to fix it. However, it still doesn't work.
My exercise: typing an address inside textbox then click on "Find Location" button. I'm using javascript to get lat and long based on given address. Everything is OK if I don't add new "form action" tag (I'm using struts2  framework). It looks like the following:

```
function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("locationId").value;
    geocoder
            .geocode(
                    {
                        'address' : address
                    },
                    function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                            document.getElementById('latId').value = results[0].geometry.location
                                    .lat().toFixed(15);
                            document.getElementById('lonId').value = results[0].geometry.location
                                    .lng().toFixed(15);
                        } else {
                            alert("Lat and long cannot be found.");
                        }
                    });
}

<s:form action="searchNearestLocation">
    <s:hidden name="latInput" id="latId" />
    <s:hidden name="lonInput" id="lonId" />
    <s:textfield name="locationName" id="locationId" />
    <s:submit value="Find Location" name="findLocation" onclick="codeAddress()" />
    <div id="googleMap" style="width: 500px; height: 380px;"></div>
</s:form>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'don't add new "form action" tag'?

Comment: I suppose you are putting the Javascript function inside `<script>` tag, right? Also, I don't know if that `<div>` within the `<s:form>` is a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, the first time I post question. When I remove "<s:form action="searchNearestLocation">", It runs normally. I have put the Javascript function inside <script> tag and move <div> outside <s:form>. But it still doesn't work. Thank for your supporting!

Comment: @user2408351 So your problem is that the Action `searchNearesLocation` doesn't get the data? I mean, `latId` and `lonId` are filled correctly by the script but the `Action` crashes? Because in that case your problem is totally different from what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, I think I have problem with struts action. I write alert(address) in function. It gets correct value of location. But geocoder returns status = ERROR. I don't know whether the struts action affects the geocoder?

Comment: @Armaggedon thank you so much. I don't really know why It doesn't work. But, I run project on the different computer and it is ok. Thanks for your supporting.

Comment: @user2408351 Well, that's weird, but I'm glad you got able to fix it :). BTW, try to always comment on someone using @ like that last time. Otherwise StackOverflow won't notify him.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this:`<s:input value="Find Location" name="findLocation" onclick="codeAddress()" action="searchNearestLocation"/>`?